# Android Retrofit 2 как задать сложный запрос

Tags: android, retrofit

Здравствуйте!
Я прочитал уже с десяток гайдов по Retrofit2, но все они объясняют только отправку простеньких @GET @POST запросов и я так и не понял как задать нужный мне запрос, так что прошу помощи у знающих людей.

Собственно такой вот запрос я хочу задать с помощью Retrofit2
"https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?lang=" + lang + "&" + "text=" + text + "&" + API_KEY

//String lang задает на какой язык перевести
//String text текс который мы переводим

Как я понимаю в классе, где создаем объект Retrofit, BASE_URL = "https://translate.yandex.net/";

В интерфейсе

```
@GET("/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?")
Call<TranslationResponce>translateText(@Query("lang")String lang, @Query("text")String text, @Query("api_key")String apiKey);
```

Но видимо понимаю я не правильно, так как этот запрос не работает. Ткните пожалуйста носом, что я делаю не так? Заранее благодарю!

Comment: А что лог пишет ?

Comment: @elik я пока не разобрался как вывести лог ответа, но знаю, что  в блоке if(response.isSuccessful()) {, код не срабатывает, так как мой лог там не выводится. Ошибок тоже не выводит.

Comment: ну ок вложи код разберем по частям

Comment: @elik что то не получается тут выложить, выдает ошибку. Посмотри пожалуйста на гите [ссылка](https://github.com/beardykun/Retrofit3/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/mikhail/pankratov/retrofit3)

Comment: @Mikhail, Из строки API_KEY уберите "key=" и `@Query("api_key")` замените на `@Query("key")`. Ещё параметр "lang" должен содержать направление перевода ('en-ru' например)

Comment: @woesss Заработало, большое спасибо! Я бы принял Ваш ответ, как правильный, если бы он не был комментарием...

Comment: @Mikhail, мой коммент не отвечает на поставленный вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите в строке с аннотаций @GET в конце вопросительный знак

Comment: Убрал, к сожалению результат не изменился

Comment: Попробуйте тогда через аннотации Query заменить на Field. И над методом GET задайте еще FormUrlEncoded

Comment: заменил, выдает ошибку java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FormUrlEncoded can only be specified on HTTP methods with request body (e.g., @POST).

Comment: Пробовал на всякий случай поменять на @POST, не помогло

Comment: Дайте ссылку на метод api к которому вы обращаетесь

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду ссылку на  [документацию](https://tech.yandex.com/translate/doc/dg/reference/translate-docpage/)?

Comment: Кстати,по поводу Вашего первого комментария, запрос работает как с вопросительным знаком, так и без